# Preferences-like Framework for multiple VM's

Tags: java

i am currently coding settings for a project.

Today i have found out that this project will be running on multiple VM's and that is why i have to scrap my Preferences Wrapper and code a new one.

What java.util.prefs.Preferences-like Frameworks are there except Properties?
I do want the ability to save more than just String types.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you need to scrap your wrapper? Why would multiple VMs affect it in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [Apache Commons Preferences](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/). It supports several formats.